# What is the data argument in click event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code snippet:

```
$("#target").bind('click', function(data) { ... });
```

What is the data argument? It's Click event's data or Function's data?

I think it's function's data, is it true?

Comment: `data` is nothing but `event` object...Better to name it as `event` to avoid any confusion...

Comment: Bind is deprecated. Currently the statement should be `$("#target").on('click', function(event) { ... });` and the argument to the handler is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event) Please look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)....

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is sufficiently answered by the current documentation

Comment: To provide a short summary: technically, data is just the name of the first argument in your (callback) function. The value itself contains whatever is passed to the function by its caller. In this case it will contain the event object described in the docs, because that's the purpose and definition of this callback. (although hypothetically, one could obtain the callback and call it with an entirely different type ;) )

Comment: A simple glance at the documentation will answer this for you. Welcome to the programming world. But please get in the habit of looking at documentation first, or you will start to see the acronym RTFM more and more. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the function passed to any jQuery event binder (like `$.on`, `$.click` or `$.bind` - which was deprecated in favor of `on`) is the event data and contains lots of information about the event that just occurred.

[image]

If you debug that object, you can see that it includes information about the type of event (e.g. `click`), the element that triggered it, the position of the element, the position on the screen, and others.

All information about that object and it's children can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 0):

The data argument is the click event object, 
for example the data.target is the clicked object.

you will find the explanation here:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/